How to keep fixed Grand Total in Looker studio
In lookerstudio I'm trying to create a chart where.
Data source (sheets)
Dimension:

Location (Internal;External,Null)

Metrics:

Out of Promise
-Total Promise Orders
-Impact (sum(Out of promise)/sum(Total Promise orders).

What I'm getting:
           Out of promise . Total Promise Orders . Impact

Internal  -          784__________________29936.66___________________2,62%
External  -          992__________________5260.34____________________18,86%
Grand total-        1776________________45,324_____________________3,92%
The results I want:
            Out of promise . Total Promise Orders .Impact

Internal  -    784________________ 29936.66____________1,73% (784/45,324)
External  -    992 _______________ 5260.34 ____________2,19% (992/45,324)
Grand total- 1776 ____________45,324 _____________3,92%
I tried to create a new table from my main data source (in sheets) where I sum the Total Promise orders by date to blend with my main source to prevent it from being affected by any filtering.
I created Col1 (Date), Col2 (sum Total Promise Orders), Col3 (count Promise date).
When blending both tables, the (sum Total Promise Orders) from table 2 is going to be summed for every row of the same date it finds in table 1, so I did Col3 to divide this value to get the correct Grande Total.
This works fine if I just want to see one day only, but If I want to see for example the sum of the week, this approach doesn't work.
Essentially, Im looking for a way to get the Grand Total of Promise Orders by Date in a way that it doesn't get affected by any other filtering, But I'm running out of Ideas on how to achieve this value.
Hope you guys can help me out.
